# Binding `click` event with jQuery: getting browser event, not jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this code:

```
$link.click(function (e) {
    debugger;
});
```

When the link is clicked and the debugger engages, `e` is a regular browser event, and not a jQuery event. There's no `.stopPropagation()` or `.preventDefault()`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$link.bind("click", function (e) {
    var jQueryEvent = e,
        browserEvent = e.originalEvent;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, as you said, it a regular browser event, and browser event doesn't have that kind of method.

To stop the propagation, just `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

`e` should be an instance of [`jQuery.Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), so those methods *should* be available:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    alert(e instanceof jQuery.Event); // true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dyJtY/

Can you provide more context, such as the debugger output?